# Limit of square root function

Tags: limits

I'm not good at math and I've already searched for a proper answer but couldn't figured it out . 
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty}\left(\sqrt{x^2 + 5x + 2} - \sqrt{x^2 + x + 1}\right)
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: multiply the given term by $$\frac{\sqrt{x^2+5x+2}+\sqrt{x^2+x+1}}{\sqrt{x^2+5x+2}+\sqrt{x^2+x+1}}$$